# How to set header cookie with angular 2

Tags: angular, cookies, request, ionic2, setcookie

Night.

This trouble came when i want to send cookie to server.
the idea is to check the user are logged in or not.

this the code

```
isLogin(): Promise<any> {
    let headers = new Headers;
    headers.append('Cookies', 'autologin=abcdef;'); //this the set cookie. but not set when i check in mozilla network tap

    return this.http.get(this.BASEURL + 'api/authentication/check', { headers: headers })
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

and this is the request header.

```
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: set-cookie
Origin: http://localhost:8100
```

this server code

```
public function check()
    {
        if ($this->auth->loggedin())
        {
            $this->output
                ->set_status_header(200)
                ->set_content_type('application/json')
                ->set_output(json_encode($this->session->userdata()));
        } else {
            $this->output
                ->set_status_header(400)
                ->set_content_type('application/json')
                ->set_output(json_encode(['status' => FALSE]));
        }
    }
```

see? no cookies in the request. help me. this stuck get me headache.. XD

Answer (score 0):

Add the `Header` object within a `RequestOptions` object.

```
isLogin(): Promise<any> {
    let headers = new Headers;
    headers.append('Cookies', 'autologin=abcdef;'); //this the set cookie. but not set when i check in mozilla network tap

    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

    return this.http.get(this.BASEURL + 'api/authentication/check', options)
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

This should work, although you're not really returning a promise since you're resolving it already (i think)
.

Import for requestoptions: `import { RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';`

Comment: No effect. response from the server just json. and cookie. <br>
request header is same as the first, cookies still not included

Comment: Hmm okay, and if you change the name of `Cookies` to for example, 'Test-Header', can you see it then or doesn't it show either?

Comment: i was tried and get nothing,
 fyi i get this error on my console: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: ....` is this the problem that make request cookies could not set?

Comment: Thats a CORS error, means the api you're calling doesn't support cross origing requests like your localhost. Is it your own api or someone else's?

Comment: that is my api i create from PHP CI 3 and use php-auth cooke library. and Ionic2 Framework. i use Xampp with php 5.6 installed.

Comment: I was tried it in my htaccess, and allow all method but it no effect